# Lower Bound on R(k,k)

Tags: ramsey-theory

I was reading about Ramsey numbers lately, and found a lower bound in a book. It stated that:

$ R(k,k) > \binom{k-1}{3} $

However it did not say the proof and I could not come up with a construction. I found that $R(k,k) \geq (k-1)^2 $, but that is not sharp enough, only for large k.

Any ideas how one could prove the firstly mentioned inequality?

Comment: Note: With the probabilistic method, we can show that $ R(k,k) > 2^{k/2} $ for $ k \geq 3$. $\quad$ Can you show how you demonstrated $ R(k,k) \geq (k-1)^2$?

Comment: Yes that is what I was looking for, thank you